# Make numpy polyfit work for numbers with large number of digits

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation, polynomials

I would like to apply `numpy.polyfit` or `Polynomial.polyfit` to 3 data points [a1,a2,a3] each of which have about 300 digits.
if I use:

```
x = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
y = numpy.array([a1, a2, a3])
c = numpy.polyfit(x,y,2)
d = Polynomial.polyfit(x,y,2)
```

I am getting inexact coefficients
And polyfit does not accept data type `dtype=object` to handle numbers with large number of digits.
Also, any way I can call MAXIMA from python to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For three points, it's a linear equations problem. You can use SymPy:

```
from sympy import S, Matrix

x1, x2, x3 = S(1), S(2), S(3)
y1, y2, y3 = S(2), S(0), S(1)

X = Matrix([
    [x1**2, x1, 1],
    [x2**2, x2, 1],
    [x3**2, x3, 1]
])
y = Matrix([
    [y1],
    [y2],
    [y3]
])

X.inv() * y
```

for more then three points, it's a linear least squares problem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)

Answer (score 0):

When double precision does not suffice, one usually has to look for other libraries such as `mpmath` or `sympy`. And `sympy` has a built-in [`interpolating_poly` function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.specialpolys.interpolating_poly):

```
from sympy import Symbol, interpolating_poly
x = Symbol('x')
xp = [1, 2, 3]
yp = [3333333333333333333333333, 77777777777777777777777777, 22222222222222222222222222222]
p = interpolating_poly(3, x, xp, yp)
```

The first argument is the number of points; the second is the symbol to be used in the polynomial. If you go this way, then do **not** write `1.0` for `1`, etc; this will coerce everything to floats and you'll be back where you were with NumPy. Symbolic computation needs integers, rationals, and symbolic expressions with those.

The result is returned in Newton polynomial form with `(x-1)`, `(x-1)*(x-2)`, etc; one can use `expand` to make it into a more familiar polynomial form:

```
p = p.expand()
```

returning `22070000000000000000000000001*x**2/2 - 66061111111111111111111111115*x/2 + 21998888888888888888888888890`. These coefficients are exact, as one can check with `[p.subs(x, v) for v in xp]`: the original `yp` values are returned.